# Creating Customer Location

Tags: acumatica

My requirement is to create a customer location part of downloading order from 3rd party shopping cart.

I have tried this below code and It is not saving any location and also not raising any error.

```
private static void CreateCustomerLocation(Customer cust, string locationcode, OrderDTO ord, OrderDownloadActivityEntry grp)
        {
            try
            {
                LocationMaint graph = CustomerLocationMaint.CreateInstance<CustomerLocationMaint>();
                SelectedLocation loc = new SelectedLocation();
                loc.BAccountID = cust.BAccountID;
                loc.LocationCD = locationcode;
                loc.Descr = ord.CustomerLocationName;
                loc.IsContactSameAsMain = false;
                loc.IsAddressSameAsMain = false;
                graph.Location.Insert(loc);

                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.Attention = ord.OrderCustomerContactName;
                contact.Phone1 = ord.OrderCustomerContactPhone;
                contact.DisplayName = ord.CustomerLocationName;
                contact.LastName = ord.OrderCustomerContactName;
                contact = graph.Contact.Update(contact);
                Address address = new Address();
                address.AddressLine1 = ord.OrderShippingLocationAddress1;
                address.AddressLine2 = ord.OrderShippingLocationAddress2;
                address.City = ord.OrderShippingLocationCity;
                address.State = ord.OrderShippingLocationState;
                address.PostalCode = ord.OrderShippingLocationZip;
                address.CountryID = "US";

                contact = graph.Contact.Update(contact);
                address = graph.Address.Update(address);
                loc.DefAddressID = address.AddressID;
                loc.DefContactID = contact.ContactID;
                graph.Location.Update(loc);
                graph.Save.Press();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                grp.AddLogData(SessionID, "Create Location", "Create Location falied", null, null, e.StackTrace);
            }
        }
```

I am not able to figure out where i am making mistake. any suggestion for this issue?

**Update**

I have tried the following code and I am getting the following error

**CARAccountLocationID' cannot be empty.**

```
private static void CreateCustomerLocation(Customer cust, string locationcode, OrderDTO ord, OrderDownloadActivityEntry grp)
        {
            try
            {
                LocationMaint graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<CustomerLocationMaint>();
                graph.BusinessAccount.Current = PXSelect<BAccount, Where<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<Required<BAccount.bAccountID>>>>.Select(graph, cust.BAccountID);
                var newLocation = (Location)graph.Location.Cache.CreateInstance();
                var locType = LocTypeList.CustomerLoc;
                newLocation.LocType = locType;
                graph.Location.Insert(newLocation);

                var loc = (Location)graph.Location.Cache.CreateCopy(graph.Location.Current);




                Contact contact = graph.Contact.Cache.CreateCopy(graph.Contact.Current) as Contact;
                contact.Attention = ord.OrderCustomerContactName;
                contact.Phone1 = ord.OrderCustomerContactPhone;
                contact.DisplayName = ord.CustomerLocationName;
                contact.LastName = ord.OrderCustomerContactName;
                contact = graph.Contact.Update(contact);
                Address address = graph.Address.Cache.CreateCopy(graph.Address.Current) as Address;
                address.AddressLine1 = ord.OrderShippingLocationAddress1;
                address.AddressLine2 = ord.OrderShippingLocationAddress2;
                address.City = ord.OrderShippingLocationCity;
                address.State = ord.OrderShippingLocationState;
                address.PostalCode = ord.OrderShippingLocationZip;
                address.CountryID = "US";
                contact = graph.Contact.Update(contact);
                address = graph.Address.Update(address);
                contact.DefAddressID = address.AddressID;
                loc.IsAddressSameAsMain = false;
                loc.IsContactSameAsMain = false;
                loc.IsAPAccountSameAsMain = true;
                loc.IsAPPaymentInfoSameAsMain = true;
                loc.IsARAccountSameAsMain = true;
                loc.LocationCD = locationcode;
                loc.Descr = ord.CustomerLocationName;
                loc = graph.Location.Update(loc);
                loc.BAccountID = cust.BAccountID;
                graph.Location.Cache.RaiseFieldUpdated<Location.isARAccountSameAsMain>(loc, null);
                if (loc.CARAccountLocationID == null)
                    loc.CARAccountLocationID = cust.DefLocationID;
                graph.Location.Update(loc);
                graph.Save.Press();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                grp.AddLogData(SessionID, "Create Location", "Create Location falied", null, null, e.StackTrace);
            }
        }
```

Comment: A search for CARAccountLocationID yields no result which leads me to believe the error message was incorrectly copied in your question. The other less likely case is that it's a custom field, should have been prefixed by Usr in that case. Or maybe it's both...

Comment: A second clue that a faulty error copy/paste occurred is that you're missing the opening quote in your question.

Comment: CARAccountLocationID is the field, BusinessAccountBase Graph uses LocationExtAddress which is a projection and picks value from CRLocation

Comment: Error: 'CARAccountLocationID' cannot be empty.

Answer (score 0):

CARAccountLocationID is the LocationID of the MAIN location for a given BAccount/Customer. It is used by the business logic when setting GLAccounts.SameAsDefaultLocationS on screen AR303020.
I've seen the "'CARAccountLocationID' cannot be empty." error when creating a location without first setting the Customer.
The resolution was to first set the customer, then set SameAsDefaultLocationS, then set the rest of the fields.
In the screen API order of operations matters.

In your case you might need to directly set loc.CARAccountLocationID to the LocationID of the customer's MAIN location.